# Are click-bait question titles unacceptable?

Tags: discussion

[Why is my son not an enormous wart?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17714/), whilst less precise and academic than:

- Why don't warts caused by HPV spread to the whole body?
- Why does a wart not spread laterally?

I don't think it's [uninformative or misleading](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7499%20changed).  It's certainly unprofessional, but I'm not a professional in this area, and I don't believe this question will be searched for by professionals (although all the professionals I've asked haven't given an acceptable answer as yet).  It could be argued that the "spread to the whole body" is clearer for non-native English speakers.

I was trying to attract eyeballs with a click-bait question title.  Is a certain level of sobriety required in question titles?  Is there an unspoken rule of decorum that was violated?

Comment: Clickbaity/funny titles are certainly celebrated on some sites, but I would imagine that this community would want to keep things a little more clinical. It is certainly up to the community, though.

Comment: As well as being clickbait, it was rather tasteless clickbait, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I did notice that title and I still remember the contents of it which means your ploy does work. I don't mind a bit of humor in the titles but it could be improved upon.